# Outputs to newfile if line contains "-" or " "

Tags: unix, text, file-io, sed, grep

Is there a way to do the following python in unix command? Maybe with sed or grep??

```
for line in open(input_file)
    if "-" or " " in line:
        print>>line , output_file
```

Comment: Do you want something like: `grep "\-\| " input_file > output_file`?

Comment: the grep command dont work with slash "\"

Comment: It may depend on what `grep` you are using. You can try to add a `-E` option to the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep "\-\| " input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it with sed:

```
sed -n '/[ -]/p' input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Does below work for you?

```
grep -P '[ -]' input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
grep -e '-' -e ' ' input_file > output_file
```